# How to rename a bundle in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, rename

My bundle is located at `src/Cinergy/Bundle/ComponentBundle/CinergyComponentBundle.php` and the logical name of the bundle is `'CinergyComponentBundle'`.

Since I did not stick to the naming convention of the company I have to change the logcial name of the bundle. Lets asume I have to rename it to `'XXXCinergyComponentBundle'`

What files do I need to change?

I tried renaming the `CinergyComponentBundle.php` file and the containing class into `XXXCinergyComponentBundle.php`. I also changed the reference in AppKernel.

Unfortunately this does not work. When I try to clear the cache I get this error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                   
The service "cinergy.people.direct.php" has a dependency on a non-existent service "cinergy.work.registry".
```

This two services do belong to the bundle with the new name. This leads me to the conclusion that I'm missing something in the renaming process.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldyUhirsrNo)

Answer (score 9):

I have just completed renaming a bundle myself and ended up at the exact same point as you did a couple of minutes ago. To this point I have used my editors replace-function. It turns out there are some files that need some extra care, which are located here (assuming your old Bundle name was AcmeOldBundle, new will be AcmeNewBundle):

1. Acme\OldBundle\OldBundle.php -> NewBundle.php
2. Acme\OldBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeOldExtension.php ->
   AcmeNewExtension.php

Do not forget to update the class-names inside the files as well.

Comment: Just echoing the above; editor/search replace won't rename the files, which are easily overlooked. So to be sure, use this: `find . -name '*AcmeOldExtension*'` and then manually rename the files (which might just be as above).

Answer (score 7):

The current answers do indeed explain what to do to rename a bundle but they leave out a few things:

1. Rename the bundle in `/app/AppKernel.php`

   From:

   ```
   $bundles = [
       // ...
       new Acme\OldBundle\AcmeOldBundle(),
   ];
   ```

   To:

   ```
   $bundles = [
       // ...
       new Acme\NewBundle\AcmeNewBundle(),
   ];
   ```
2. Renaming files and folders

   You need to rename the files and folders containing your code:

   ```
   src/Acme/OldBundle -> src/Acme/NewBundle
   src/Acme/OldBundle/OldBundle.php -> src/Acme/NewBundle/NewBundle.php

   # If present
   src/Acme/OldBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeOldExtension.php -> src/Acme/NewBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeNewExtension.php
   ```
3. Namespaces

   This will probably go with forgetting a few files and searching around your bundle for each and every match. The best thing to do is doing a find-replace:

   ```
   # find -> replace
   acme_old -> acme_new
   Acme\OldBundle\ -> Acme\NewBundle
   AcmeOld -> AcmeNew
   Acme:Old -> Acme:New
   Acme:OldBundle -> Acme:NewBundle
   ```

   Be sure to check all namespaces, class names and configuration files in your bundle.
4. Global configuration files

   Search for any occurrence of your old bundle name in `app/config/` and replace it with your new bundle name.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the entire namespace in each files.

You were using `namespace Cynergy\ComponentBundle\Something;` but you're now using `namespace XXXCynergy\ComponentBundle\Something;`

Don't forget to update your `services.(xml|yml)`.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not correct. I'm not changing the path of the bundle. I'm only changing the logical name.

Comment: Then you're wrong, because of PSR-0/1/2 you need to map your namespace with the filesystem, or manually set the autoloader.

Comment: I'm changing the name of one class and it's PHP file only. I'm not changing the name of an entire namespace/directory. Since AppKernel happyly finds the renamed class, I doubt that there's an autoloader/class/file name issue.

Comment: Mmm. You should really check why the DIC can't load your service. It tells you that it doesn't exist, why doesn't it exist? Is it correctly defined in your services configuration? Does the service actually exist?