# symfony2 bundle extension is not loaded after renaming the bundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have created a new bundle called PostalAddressBundle and i created a service inside it called ss_postal_address. Everything was working fine. But i decided to rename the bundle to AddressBundle instead of PostalAddressBundle, i renamed all namespace and all things related to it. Everything is working but not the service (ss_postal_address).

I cleared the cache, but nothing happens..

this is the content of services.xml file:

```
 <parameters>
        <parameter key="ss_address.entity.address.class">Skonsoft\AddressBundle\Entity\Address</parameter>
        <parameter key="ss_address.form.type.address.class">Skonsoft\AddressBundle\Form\Type\AddressType</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="ss_address.form.type.address" class="%ss_address.form.type.address.class%">
            <argument>%ss_address.entity.address.class%</argument>
            <tag name="form.type" alias="ss_postal_address" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Have you any idea how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem but just removing the cache by hand:

```
rm -Rf ./app/cache/*
```

`symfony cache:clear`  does not do the work in this case.

Comment: I also faced a similar problem. This was the solution for me as well. However in my case, it was an environment problem: I cleared dev env with the symfony command, but the application ran in production env.

Comment: Yes,  manual deletion of cache directory helped... in my case it is application_directory/var/cache

Answer (score 5):

Have you renamed your DI extension accordingly? For example a bundle named `SkonsoftAddressBundle` should have an extension named `SkonsoftAddressExtension` within the `Skonsoft\AddressBundle\DependencyInjection` namespace.

Comment: Yes i did it. i checked all class names, files and namespaces. as shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527019/how-to-change-a-bundle-name-in-symfony-2

Comment: If it is not that, I don't see... The extension is responsible of loading your services definition (xml) so if this part is the only one which fails, it should be related.